# passing repetitive attributes of programically generated buttons

Tags: java, android, button

I am generating a lot of buttons using up to 30 "for" loops and almost all of the code for these is the same.
I was wondering if it is possible to somehow get my "button.set" attributes outside my "for" loop to pass it to other loops as well.

```
   for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {

        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setId(i);
        button.setLayoutParams(params);
        button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        button.setAllCaps(false);
        button.setTextScaleX(0.92f);
        button.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#70553B"));
        button.getBackground().setAlpha(20);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        button.setMaxLines(1);
        button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        buttonHolder[i] = button;
        side_a.addView(button);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a function that takes a Button and applies all the settings to it:

```
   public void setButtonParams(Button button){
        button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        button.setAllCaps(false);
        button.setTextScaleX(0.92f);
        button.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#70553B"));
        button.getBackground().setAlpha(20);

        button.setMaxLines(1);
        button.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
   }
   for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {

        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setId(i);
        button.setLayoutParams(params);
        setButtonParams(button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonHolder[i] = button;
        side_a.addView(button);
    }
```

If you want to also set id and other values that depend on context, you can add them as parameters to the `setButtonParams` function.

Comment: I tried setButtonParams before but i must had done something wrong.
Thank You!